# JButton display issue

Tags: swing, jframe, jbutton

I have created a `JFrame` by creating a class(`Display.java`) that extends `JFrame` class. In that class I have created a `JPanel` object.

```
class Display extends JFrame {
        JPanel jp= new JPanel();
```

And in another class(`TestBroadCastNode.java`) I am adding `JButton`s to that `JPanel` by using reference to the class `Display` as shown below:

```
class TestBroadCastNode {

    Display disp;
    Graphics g =disp.getGraphics();
    JButton bt = new JButton("One");
    disp.jp.add(bt);
}
```

Now I am not able to display the buttons. Help me.... If you want I can send you the complete file.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing all the code. One possibility is that you aren't adding the JPanel to the JFrame in the Display class. If you are, try setting a layout on the panel by changing it to new JPanel(new BorderLayout()), then when you add the button, use jp.add(bt, BorderLayout.CENTER). If neither of those helps, you could try posting more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to match your code as close as possible, but since you only gave limited snippets I had to make some assumptions. But the following code shows the button just fine:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestClass {

  public static class Display extends JFrame {
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel(  );

    public Display(){
      super( "TestFrame");
      getContentPane().add( panel );
    }
  }

  public static class TestBroadCastNode{
    Display display;

    public TestBroadCastNode( Display aDisplay ) {
      display = aDisplay;
      display.panel.add( new JButton( "One" ) );
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        Display display = new Display();
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        new TestBroadCastNode( display );

        display.pack();
        display.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```